# Saving Files in the Same Directory (Input Needed)

Tags: python, file, directory, kivy, pong

I've been following this tutorial: http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html to try and learn some kivy. It says I need to save the basic app file and the file with the graphics in the same directory. I don't know how to do this. I tried saving them in the same folder, but it shows a black screen. Any feedback is appreciated.

EDIT: In Windows(C:) I have the files:

dell,
Drivers,
Intel,
main.py,
PerfLogs,
Program Files,
Python 33,
Python 34,
User, and
Windows.

Inside main.py I have programs named main.py and pong.kv. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? After copy-pasting the code at the end of the tutorial and trying to run main.py, it becomes really glitchy and you can see the the rest of the screen behind it, if that makes sense.

EDIT: The error mentioned below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\pong_app.py\main.py.py", line 74, in <module>
     PongApp().run()
   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 766, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\pong_app.py\main.py.py", line 68, in build
     game.serve_ball()
   File "C:\pong_app.py\main.py.py", line 36, in serve_ball
     self.ball.center = self.center
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'
```

Comment: you just need a `main.py` file for kivy and  `.kv` file. The completed version of both are down the end of your link, copy  and paste `main.py`,`pong.kv` and you are done.

Comment: The tutorial works well. You probably only have a simple mistake like a typo in a filename. Could you edit your question by providing the list of the files in your directory (`ls` on Linux, `dir` on Windows)...

Comment: So you named a directory on your C: 'main.py' and have a 'main.py' file and 'pong.kv' file inside of that, and each of those files has the correct code you copied and pasted from the tutorial?

Comment: @ brousch - Yes, that's right.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. Try naming the folder that your main.py and .kv files are in something like 'pong_app'. Not sure if this is creating a naming conflict in your code.

Comment: I renamed  the directory pong_app.py, but now I have an error. I edited it into my original post.